# Electromagnetic Induction With ends of coil connected

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

What happens when you move the magnet towards a coil whose ends have been connected to each other? With open ends I understand that an emf will be induced.

Answer (score 0):

An emf is still induced (Faraday) and as there is a complete conducting circuit the emf produces an induced current which is in such a direction as to oppose the change producing it (Lenz).